# Declaring a bash function inside a docker image

Tags: bash, docker, function, declare

Using a Dockerfile to build an image which I later use to run a container used to cross-compile a binary for a target platform. This container is used for development, so I work hours inside this container. The "make" command is building the binary properly.

For debug purposes, I need the output of the make command being saved to a logfile transparently. I solved this adding a bash "make" function to my Dockefile:

```
RUN echo 'make() { DATE=$(date "+%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"); LOGNAME=build_$DATE.log; $(which make) "$@" 2>&1 | tee /tmp/$LOGNAME; }' >> ~/.bashrc
```

As you can see, I modify the .bashrc. Function "make" is declared when I run into the container. Inside the container, whenever I run "make" command,  the logs are always saved into /tmp/$LOGNAME, as expected.

I wonder if there is a more convenient / clean way to define a bash function in the running shell without defining this RUN command in the Dockefile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most paths of invoking Docker containers don't read shell dotfiles or have well-defined concepts of home directories.  It's rarely useful to write to a `.bashrc` in your Dockerfile since it's highly likely that file won't be read; for example, `docker run --rm your-image make` won't read the `.bashrc` file before trying to run the `make` command.

What you can do is write these commands into a *shell script*.  This is just a file with a list of commands that will be run.  Outside of Docker, create a simple file:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# ^^ Name the interpreter that will run this script.
# This must be the absolute very first line of the file.
# Use /bin/sh in most cases; many images do not have GNU bash.
# (And make sure to avoid bash-specific syntax, like "function"
# or "source").

# This is the sequence of commands you had originally,
# one to a line.
DATE=$(date "+%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
LOGNAME="build_$DATE.log"
make "$@" 2>&1 | tee "/tmp/$LOGNAME"
```

Mark this script as executable and run it.

```bash
chmod +x make_and_log
./make_and_log compile
ls -l build_*.log
tail build_20220706-063319.log
```

Now in your Dockerfile, you just need to copy this script into somewhere that's in the standard `$PATH` directories; `/usr/local/bin` is frequently a good choice.

```bash
COPY make_and_log /usr/local/bin/
```

You can't use shell scripts like this if they need to modify environment variables in the containing shell (if you needed to `export LOGNAME` and use it later) but this script doesn't need that.  Otherwise, a shell script will generally be a little easier to manage than a shell function.  In this case note that we've never needed to escape a quote inside a quoted string we're writing out to a file; we've just written the script and hand-tested it separately from the Docker setup.

Since this is now an ordinary program in a normal place, you can just run it

```bash
docker run --rm \
  -v "$PWD:/src" -w /src \
  the-image \
  make_and_log compile
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing so valuable information. It was very helpful. Marked your answer as the proper solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

I will

- Externalize your Bash function in a dedicated file `make.sh` aside your `Dockerfile`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

make() {
   DATE=$(date "+%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
   LOGNAME=build_$DATE.log
   $(which make) "$@" 2>&1 | tee /tmp/$LOGNAME
}
```

- Add a `Dockerfile` instruction to copy the `make.sh` script in the container:

```
COPY make.sh ~/make.sh
```

- Add a `Dockerfile` instruction to source the `make.sh` script in the `.bashrc`:

```
RUN echo "source ~/make.sh" >> .bashrc
```

### [ EDIT ]

After reading @david-maze [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72882048/5472004) getting rid of the `.bashrc` sourcing part and copying the script directly under `/usr/local/bin` seems to be a more efficient and cleaner way since it allows calling the function both from inside and outside the container.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this comment, this was also helpful as provides a cleaner way to organize my custom solution.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to fully control your `.bashrc` file from within the host and copy it to the image with a Dockerfile `COPY` instruction.