# Three-word alias in bash

Tags: bash, docker, shell, alias

For some intellectual curiosity and to fix a bug, I want to create a three word alias in bash from a .sh file that then gets copied and sourced in my bashsrc.

My goal was that :

- if a user type in the terminal  `rails test test/` the terminal actually executes `rails test`
- if a user types in the terminal `rails test test/controllers/file1.rb`, the alias I create does not impact this and the terminal actually execute `rails test test/controllers/file1.rb`

It was inspired by

- multi word alias - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/670978 (but only use 2 words alias while i need three words alias)
- declare bash function in dockerfile - https://stackoverflow.com/a/72879949

**aliasRailsTest.sh**

```
rails() {
  if [ "$1" = "test" ]  && [ "$2" = "test/" ] ; then
    shift
    rails test "$@"
  else 
    command rails "$@"
  fi
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
COPY .devcontainer/aliasRailsTest.sh /home/$USERNAME/aliasRailsTest.sh
# source the make.sh script in the .bashrc
RUN echo "source /home/$USERNAME/aliasRailsTest.sh" >> "/home/$USERNAME/.bashrc"
```

It does not work. I tried removing the line 'shift' on the `aliasRailsTest.sh` file but it did not work either.

I know for sure the Dockerfile works because I checked bashsrc and my script was there, and also when I started the .sh file was only targeting 2 words alias and it used to work, so I know this part is OK. The issue very likely comes from the .sh file because I moved to 3 words alias.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I mention in the second question you link to that most paths to running Docker containers don't read shell dotfiles and often don't run a shell at all.  Are you sure this shell function is actually getting called?  Does the shell-script approach I suggest in that question work for you?

Comment: I'm using github Codespace with devcontainer/dotfiles, so maybe it's not a mainstream case but I'm sure it reads the shell dotfile because I had it working with an alias of 2 words. I tried to go the fastest route due to my newbie level and felt the shell file was faster. But your approach seemded cleaner and i might switch to it in the long term. Thanks a lot for all your insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to check length of argument in your function. You can use:

```bash
rails() {
  if [[ $# = 2 && $1 = test && $2 = test/ ]]; then
    command rails "$1"
  else 
    command rails "$@"
  fi
}
```